# Trigger not updating parent field with child field

Tags: trigger, relationships

I have a problem with a trigger.

I have this situation:

[image]

Question is: At each insertion of "Registrazione Visita", the owner's "Da pagare" field will be updated with the costs of visits made by that owner's animals.

My trigger now is:

```
trigger UpdateCosti on Registrazione_Visita__c (after insert) {          
    Set<id> TipologiaIds = new Set<id>();
    Set<id> animaliIds = new Set<id>();
    
    for (Registrazione_Visita__c  v : trigger.new) {
        TipologiaIds.add(v.Tipologia_visita__c);
        animaliIds.Add(v.Animale__c);
    }
            
    Animale__c animal = [SELECT Name, Proprietario__r.Da_pagare__c FROM Animale__c WHERE Id in:animaliIds];
    Tipologia_visita__c tip = [SELECT Costo__c FROM Tipologia_visita__c WHERE Id in:TipologiaIds];
    
    animal.Proprietario__r.Da_pagare__c += tip.Costo__c;
}
```

but the owner's "Da Pagare" field does not update;

any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As the "Da Pagare" field is on a different object to the one your trigger is handling, you will need to explcity `update` that record (or records) in your trigger.

Also consider that there can be multiple records involved so you need to code for that situation too.

Answer (score 0):

You should explict call an update on `Proprietario__c` records.
You should also build a bulkified logic in your trigger and would be good to move it in an handler class. At the moment the SOQL on `Animale__c` will throw an exception if in the same transaction you create at least two `Registrazione_Visita__c` records related to different "Animali".
Lastly you don't need two SOQL since the trigger is on an object that has lookup fields to the other required objects.

```java
trigger UpdateCosti on Registrazione_Visita__c (after insert) {          
    Map<Id, Proprietario__c> mapIdProprietario = new Map<Id, Proprietario__c>();
    
    for (Registrazione_Visita__c  registrazione : [SELECT Tipologia_visita__r.Costo__c, Animale__r.Proprietario__c, Animale__r.Proprietario__r.Da_pagare__c FROM Registrazione_Visita__c WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new]) {
        Proprietario__c proprietario = mapIdProprietario.get(registrazione.Animale__r.Proprietario__c);
        if (proprietario == null) {
            proprietario = new Proprietario__c(Id = registrazione.Animale__r.Proprietario__c);
            proprietario.Da_pagare__c = registrazione.Animale__r.Proprietario__r.Da_pagare__c != null : registrazione.Animale__r.Proprietario__r.Da_pagare__c : 0;
            mapIdProprietario.put(proprietario.Id, proprietario);
        }
        proprietario.Da_pagare__c += registrazione.Tipologia_visita__r.Costo__c
    }
            
    update mapIdProprietario.values();
}
```